# Usage of "kick in"

Tags: idioms, prepositions

Is the following usage of the words "kick in" proper?

Is this:

> The rollover will only kick in in the next billing cycle.

better than this?

> The rollover will kick in the next billing cycle.

Is the extra "in" required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legal? At least in the UK the law doesn't normally control the language we use. But, yes, *kick in* is a phrasal verb meaning 'come into effect' or 'come into operation'. You don't need to worry about it being followed by another *in*. In fact, in your example it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could always say

> The rollover will kick in ***at*** the next billing cycle.

or

> The rollover will kick in ***on*** the next billing cycle.

**EDIT:** (to answer the "is in required" part)

Either would avoid the repeating "in", which I think is helpful, but not absolutely required. Without it, the phrase "the next billing cycle" is adverbial, like saying "next month", so it would be like saying...

> I am going to pay my bill on time (the) next billing cycle.

...which sounds awkward to me, because a billing cycle is another kind of beast that has dates associated with it, but not precisely the same thing as a time span like "next month".

Comment: @Theta30: If you include the double "in" it will sound awkward. Jeff's suggestion is reasonable.

Comment: @Theta30: I think he was indirectly saying that, yes, it's necessary, but here's how you can get around it.

Comment: i could also say "during", but that's not what I am really asking. Also we are usually casual when we say things, but put them down in an email and MS Word Grammar checker tries to play big brother. I could also rephrase it by saying "in the next billing cycle, the rollover will kick-in".

Comment: To rephrase my answer, then, @abhi: both forms are proper, the first is better (but awkward), and the extra "in" is not required.